# How to sort a table in Lua based on current date

Tags: lua, lua-table

I need an array which will start with today's date as the first element and sort all of the others in that order.

```
self.dayw=tonumber(os.date("%w")) --today's date
this is the array I have already implemented
 self.dayArray[1]=response["monday"]
 self.dayArray[2]=response["tuesday"]
 self.dayArray[3]=response["wednesday"]
 self.dayArray[4]=response["thursday"]
 self.dayArray[5]=response["friday"]
 self.dayArray[6]=response["saturday"]
 self.dayArray[7]=response["sunday"]
```

So if today is Friday, I need that array to start from Friday as the first element.

I have created sortArray={} and tried to fill it with elements depending on the day, but the code is too "hectic" and there is probably a smarter solution to this. If you can please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each day of the week is assigned a number, starting from Sunday at `1` and ending with Saturday at `7`. In order to find this numerical representation of the current day, call `os.date("*t")`, which returns a table filled with information about the current day, month, year, etc. The field within this table that corresponds to the current day's number is called `wday`.

```
for k, v in pairs(os.date("*t")) do
    print(k, v)
end
```

Output:

```
year    2020
wday    6
month   8
isdst   true
hour    21
day 28
sec 13
yday    241
min 48
```

Here, the value associated with key `wday` is `6`, which corresponds to Friday.

With this number, you can reorder your table of days by popping elements before the current day and then reinserting them at the end.

```
-- Local references to table functions.
local tblins = table.insert
local tblrmv = table.remove

local days = {
    "Sunday",
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday",
    "Saturday"
}

local function reorder(days, wday)
    for i = wday - 1, 1, -1 do
        -- Pop element days[1] and then append it.
        tblins(days, tblrmv(days, 1))
    end
    return
end

local date_table = os.date("*t")
reorder(days, date_table.wday)

for i, day in ipairs(days) do
    print(i, day)
end
```

Output:

```
1   Friday
2   Saturday
3   Sunday
4   Monday
5   Tuesday
6   Wednesday
7   Thursday
```

If you wanted an easily restartable version, here is an expansion of my existing solution:

```
-- Local references to table functions.
local tblins = table.insert
local tblrmv = table.remove
local tblsrt = table.sort

-- The field `day' refers to the string representation; `num' refers to the
-- given day's original position in the table, which is used to restore the
-- table to its starting order.
local days = {
    {day = "Sunday", num = 1},
    {day = "Monday", num = 2},
    {day = "Tuesday", num = 3},
    {day = "Wednesday", num = 4},
    {day = "Thursday", num = 5},
    {day = "Friday", num = 6},
    {day = "Sunday", num = 7}
}

local function sort_days(left_day, right_day)
    return left_day.num < right_day.num
end

-- The reorder function remains the same
-- To put the days table back in its original order, call the following:
tblsrt(days, sort_days)

for i, day in ipairs(days) do
    print(i, day.day, day.num)
end
```

Output:

```
1   Sunday  1
2   Monday  2
3   Tuesday 3
4   Wednesday   4
5   Thursday    5
6   Friday  6
7   Saturday    7
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this has helped :)